# How to reset ViewContainerRef in angular2 after change Detection?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular2-template

So I am working on this app in which I have used `ViewContainerRef` along with `dynamicComponentLoader` like below:

**generic.component.ts**

```
export class GenericComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges{
    @ViewChild('target', { read: ViewContainerRef }) target;
    @Input('input-model') inputModel: any = {};
    constructor(private dcl: DynamicComponentLoader) { }
    ngAfterViewInit() {            
        this.dcl.loadNextToLocation(DemoComponent,this.target)
            .then(ref => {
                if (this.inputModel[this.objAttr] === undefined) {
                    ref.instance.inputModel = this.inputModel;
                } else {
                    ref.instance.inputModel[this.objAttr] = this.inputModel[this.objAttr];                        
                }
            });
            console.log('Generic Component :===== DemoComponent===== Loaded');
    }

   ngOnChanges(changes) {
       console.log('ngOnChanges - propertyName = ' + JSON.stringify(changes['inputModel'].currentValue));
       this.inputModel=changes['inputModel'].currentValue;                
   }
}
```

**generic.html**

```
<div #target></div>
```

So It renders the `DemoComponent`in `target` element correctly.

but when I am changing the `inputModel` then I want to reset the view of target element.

I tried `onOnChanges` to reset the inputModel , its getting changed correctly but the view is not getting updated for respective change.

So I want to know if is it possible to reset the view inside `ngOnChanges` after the `inputModel` is updated?

any inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no connection between `this.inputModel` and `ref.instance.inputModel`. If one changes you need to copy it again.

For example like:

```
export class GenericComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges{
    componentRef:ComponentRef;

    @ViewChild('target', { read: ViewContainerRef }) target;
    @Input('input-model') inputModel: any = {};
    constructor(private dcl: DynamicComponentLoader) { }
    ngAfterViewInit() {            
        this.dcl.loadNextToLocation(DemoComponent,this.target)
            .then(ref => {
                this.componentRef = ref;
                this.updateModel();
            });
            console.log('Generic Component :===== DemoComponent===== Loaded');
    }

 
    updateModel() {
        if(!this.componentRef) return;

        if (this.inputModel[this.objAttr] === undefined) {
            this.componentRef.instance.inputModel = this.inputModel;
        } else {
            this.componentRef.instance.inputModel[this.objAttr] = this.inputModel[this.objAttr];                        
        }
    }

   ngOnChanges(changes) {
       console.log('ngOnChanges - propertyName = ' + JSON.stringify(changes['inputModel'].currentValue));
       this.inputModel=changes['inputModel'].currentValue;                
       this.updateModel();
   }
}
```

Comment: `ref` is not available inside `updateModel()` ,should I use `this.componentRef`? @Gunter

Comment: its not working.the view is not getting updated, it shows error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'instance' of undefined`

Comment: That's probably because `ngOnChanges()` is called before `ngAfterViewInit()`. Just add a check if `this.componentRef` is set - I updated my answer.